# Employer opening website accounts on my behalf without consent

Tags: privacy, australia

My employer (more specifically: HR) keeps opening free website accounts on my behalf (using my name, work email and DOB) on websites. Some are work-related, some are not, but in no case are relevant to the job that I'm doing. For example, some provide benefits like restaurant coupons, etc. No money is spent by HR or my employer. These voucher sites are paid for by data mining companies. And that's where the issue lays: You pay for a 10% discount with your privacy (and a ton of ads in your inbox).

Arguing with a bad image is a good idea, and it might work if the company would be smaller. But even HR are pretty much detached. My employer is a global IT company, with branches in five continents. This entire thing is sanctioned by the very head of HR and has the CEO's and board's blessing.

How can I let HR know that I don't want this (I'm happy to forfeit the benefits of these website, as they don't apply to me/I won't use them at all). Should I argue with privacy, which I'm concerned about (running the risk of bewildering them as most people don't even have an idea of what privacy is), or should I simply state that I don't wish to have these accounts because I don't need them?

If I knew it were illegal, I'd argue with the illegality, but I have not been able to determine whether this is legal or not (in Australia). I've found no answer to this question on the net, not even FairWorks or HumanRights have an answer. I could ask a solicitor/lawyer, but there must be an answer to this out there without spending 100 bucks in consultation fee...

---

Edit: I've closed the accounts today by talking to the website ops directly. Let's see if HR comes back to me. I may then need to cite my contract, the law or simply what constitutes good manners to them.

Thanks so much for all the answers.

Comment: Hi Hamilton, welcome to the Workplace! I edited your question to remove the legal aspect, since [we don't answer legal questions here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2694/16983). Focusing on how to approach your boss and HR should still be on topic though and can hopefully get you a good answer!

Comment: IANAL - opening an account using another person's name sounds like **impersonation** to me.

Comment: It's not that my employer **pretends** to be me on these accounts. It's just like I'd open a Facebook account for user "rath", using your name, email and DOB, and send you the account activation link. Needless to say that I don't even activate these accounts. But that's a technicality. The account is still there.

Comment: How big is your company? Is there one HR person, and above them is the CEO who you could talk to as well? Or are you at a huge corporation with an entire HR department? If closer to the latter, is this HR standard procedure, or is there one rogue HR person?

Comment: It's a huge corp with their own HR dep. And this entire thing is sanctioned by the very head of HR and has the CEO's and boards blessing.

Comment: @Hamilton A huge corp is handing out your private information like DOB like free candy to spammers? Do you guys have no privacy laws over there?

Comment: We do have privacy laws, mind you. But like all civil laws (aka Common Law): Being right is not enough. Getting your right costs money. If they weren't ignorant about privacy, they'd still do it, and speculate that nobody dares to challenge them legally. **However**, I'll spend a good portion of tomorrow to dig out the Privacy Act 1988, and see if it covers this scenario. However, filing a lawsuit would be my last resort

Comment: If it's all by invitation, that's fine. Then every employee can decide for or against it. In regards breaking the law: You'd be surprised how many things in the past were in the legal gray area. Can't give details as that'd identify me in case they read along. Yet, no one dares to challenge this, for various reasons. I'd say: The bigger the company, the more likely they bend or break the law. I'll check my contract, that's a good idea.

Comment: Sounds like someone has messed up big time. You just need to connect the right level of exec with the cost of replacing you, or compensating you.

Comment: Can you clarify how many sites we're talking about here, whether they're legit or incredibly shady/dodgy as you imply? But really, reading your comment "*this entire thing is sanctioned by the very head of HR and has the CEO's and boards blessing*" means there's probably very little you can do.

Comment: So far, three sites. They are all legit. Alas, you can even talk to them via email or IM!

Comment: Legal or company-specific advice is off topic, voting to close.

Comment: My two cents: answering all that junk in your inbox, unsubscribing all those newsletters costs time. I don't think that your manager wants your time wasted. Maybe you can tackle the topic in this way.

Comment: @jwsc, good idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two aspects to this question. One is legal, the other professional.

From a legal POV, you need to talk to a lawyer. If it costs 100 bucks to get an answer/advice, so be it.

From a professional POV, there's a couple of things you can do. First of all, *why* is HR opening these accounts for you? Are they standard accounts which all employees must have? Is someone in HR specifically opening accounts *only for you*?

I would simply approach the HR manager and request that in the future they send you the links to sites, and allow you to sign up. At that point you might be able to refuse one account of another.

> Hi *[HR manager name here]*, I wanted to talk to you about these accounts which have been made for me. I feel very uncomfortable having someone else use my personal information to create accounts in my name. In the future may I please ask you to send me the links, and allow me to create my own accounts if I need them?

At the end of the day there's probably no good way to make them stop that will work if they still do it when you've asked them not to.

Comment: Sorry, it's not my manager. It's HR that's doing it. No, the accounts are not   required for work. They provide benefits such as restaurant coupons etc. I have edited my question to make it clearer that it's HR, not my manager.

Comment: @Hamilton Restaurant coupons? Is that something that could be used for your job (taking out clients, etc)?

Comment: No, I'm a software engineer. I write code. In fact, I get paid rather poorly, compared to the industry standard, so I'm a bit on a budget when it comes to eating out. **Wait a minute.** Is my employer trying to be cynical? "Let's pay them sub-par rates, and then give them restaurant vouchers!"

Comment: This sounds like an absolutely, totally, misguided attempt by HR or more likely by one specific person in HR to be "helpful". Go to HR and complain. Tell them YOU DO NOT WANT to be signed up for anything and to become a spam magnet. And ask them WHAT ARE THEY THINKING.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't want to be that aggressive (although I fantasise about opening a Facebook account in their personal name, so they get an idea of what privacy and identity theft means). All I want is for them to understand that it's not right to do this, as every person should have control over what he/she signs up for and not.

Comment: @hamilton - so how do you propose that they should find out that _"it's not right to do this"_ unless you tell them? Maybe the specific wording doesn't work for you, but unless you speak up nothing will change.

Comment: Yes, but what I say needs to be meaningful to them. Being aggressive will get me in corporate hell (read: unemployment). Simply saying that "it's not right" is good, but I lack the arguments to make them understand **why** it's not right, since the history of their actions prove that they have absolutely no idea of what privacy actually is.

Comment: @hamilton - so rather than going up to them and asking them to stop you propose that trying to explain the morality of the situation will work better? If they disagree with your POV then you're getting mired in a strange and ultimately damaging debate. If you go up and say "i'm not comfortable with your actions", then it's no longer a debatable issue. Your feelings and emotions are not debatable. And in this day and age these people would have to be particularly big assholes to continue to make you feel uncomfortable.

Comment: Good point. They can't tell me how to feel about it. But their track record has also shown that they care little. But I can try that, certainly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you work at a multi-national corporation and this "benefits program" is completely sanctioned by the director of HR and the CEO, you are not likely going to be able to change the existing process much. However, the process may already be in place, but you are just unaware.

Contact your HR through whatever means your company offers (personal representative, phone hotline, email listserv, etc). Just start by asking if there's any way to have them stop signing you up for websites. Maybe they already have a list somewhere they can add you to, or maybe they've already registered you for everything so you shouldn't get any new emails. And maybe they'll tell you that it's part of the standard benefits package and there's nothing you can do but not activate the accounts. In that case you're out of luck, unless you want to get a lawyer involved.

The only way HR will stop this practice is if someone threatens a lawsuit and/or proves that what they are doing is illegal. This could take a lot of time, effort, and money, so it's up to you how far down this path you want to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, a blacklist might be something they have (and this is the first time in my life I'd be happy to be on a blacklist). As for stopping the process altogether, you're right: I'd be extremely hard to do that. I figured that when talking to HR about unrelated matters in the past. As for the accounts: I'm desperately trying to get the websites to simply delete my accounts, but their argument is that they can't do it since their created by my employer. Sounds skewed.

Answer (score 0):

In France, we would say the [work council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_council) is over zealous.

Seems like employees perks are directly manged by the HR in your country, but the result is the same : they have a budget, and they spend it on your name without your authorization.

As the HR is a direct arm for the uper management, and not elected as our work council, you have to be more subtle than simply protesting(I won't vote for you is an efficient lever - unfortunately you don't have it). You have to convince them it is in ***their*** best interest to keep from opening those accounts. Like "it gives our firm a bad image", "it's sad to waste money on products I'm not going to use", etc.....

Don't speak about your own interest, or only as a secondary point. It's not their problem. Their problem is to protect the firm from the employees. Tell them it's not good for the firm.

Comment: The OP hasn't indicated whether these sites need to be paid for or not. They could all be free.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Interesting how things are run in France! As for the money: No money is spent by HR or my employer. These voucher sites are paid for by data mining companies. And that's where the issue lays: You pay for a 10% discount with your privacy (and a ton of ads in your inbox). Arguing with a bad image is a good idea. And it'd work if the company would be smaller. But even HR are pretty much detached. My employer is a global IT company, with branches in all continents (except Africa and Antarctica). So nobody is going to take anything serious unless it affects them personally.

Comment: @DavidK No these sites are "free". But as stated above: You pay otherwise.

Comment: @Hamilton "and a ton of ads in your inbox" Indeed with will take time to deal with. Money might not be spend, but it does cost them money.